# What does rcu_note_context_switch mean when debugging context switches on a Java thread?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, process, real-time

I am trying to determine why thousands of context switches are happening to my isolated process as described here [Why one non-voluntary context switch per second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037070/why-one-non-voluntary-context-switch-per-second/14127912#14127912) so I am tracing the kernel with `ftrace`.

My Java thread is NOT doing any I/O or any blocking. It is on a busy spin incrementing a long variable, that's it.

Using the `function` tracer I see a bunch of this:

```
java-3372  [002] .N..  5366.541160: rcu_note_context_switch <-__schedule
java-3372  [002] d...  5366.541163: finish_task_switch <-__schedule
java-3372  [002] .N..  5366.553137: rcu_note_context_switch <-__schedule
java-3372  [002] d...  5366.553139: finish_task_switch <-__schedule
java-3372  [002] .N..  5366.565113: rcu_note_context_switch <-__schedule
java-3372  [002] d...  5366.565115: finish_task_switch <-__schedule
```

Does anyone know what `rcu_note_context_switch` means?

My kernel is 3.5.0-17-generic on Ubuntu.

I am also missing the tracer `sched_switch` so I used the `function` tracer. I did some research but I think I will have to recompile my kernel to get this `sched_switch` available to ftrace. Not sure what to do. Here is my `ftrace` available tracers. As you can see there is no `sched_switch` :\

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/available_tracers
blk function_graph mmiotrace wakeup_rt wakeup function nop
```

Comment: Nothing at all else is running?  Nothing is periodically checking with a server for updates? No AV running?  No idle BitTorrent service?  Nothing?

Comment: What rate are these inexplicable context-changes happening?